# Automate Microsoft Project from C++

Tags: c++, ms-project

We're trying to read an .MPP file using a C++ code sequence. The following code raises "access violation" exceptions, although it looks like it should work.

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
    int main()

{
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    _MSProjectPtr pApp;
    auto hr = pApp.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Application));
    variant_t toOpen = _T("d:\\work\\Test.mpp");
    variant_t readOnly = true;
    variant_t merge = false;
    auto status = pApp->FileOpen(toOpen, readOnly, merge, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing,
        vtMissing, MSProject::pjDoNotOpenPool);
    auto pProject = pApp->GetActiveProject();
    auto pSummaryTask = pProject->GetProjectSummaryTask();
    auto summaryStart = pSummaryTask->GetStart(); // Access violation raised by this instruction
    auto pTasks = pProject->Tasks; // This call succeeds.
    auto count = pTasks->Count; // Access violation raised by this instruction.
    // Fails at this line with MSP 15.0.4805.1001 (in About box, 15.0.4569.1506 in Control Panel)

    pApp->Quit(MSProject::PjSaveType::pjDoNotSave);
    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```

The content of the file stdafx.h follows:

```
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSPRJ.OLB" auto_search
using namespace MSProject;
```

Is there an initialization step we're missing?

Comment: You are not checking any return values. Are you sure you are not retrieving a nullptr?

Comment: @H. Guijt: I've run the code under debugger and I've checked the status, the FileOpen call succeeds.

Comment: How about GetActiveProject()? How about GetProjectSummaryTask()? Dereferencing pSummaryTask causes the access violation, so that's a good sign that pointer is not as it should be.

Comment: I've already checked these pointers as well, they are not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this problem too,and finally use
"use the Visual C++ ClassWizard to generate "wrapper classes" from the Microsoft Office type libraries" fix it.

```
  CMSProject app;
  app.CreateDispatch(L"MSProject.Application");
  auto b = app.FileNew(vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing, vtMissing);
  app.SetVisible(TRUE);
  CIProjectDoc p = (LPDISPATCH)app.GetActiveProject();
  CTasks ts = p.get_Tasks();
  auto n = ts.get_Count();
  ts.Add((variant_t)L"abc", vtMissing);
```